# Python 2.7 tkinter - opposite of widget.tk_focusNext().focus()

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

With python 2.7 tkinter on linux the command `e.widget.tk_focusNext().focus()` work fine to focus the next widget. But how i can do the opposite? I want to focus the previous widget, how?
The actual code is this:

```
def select(e):
    if e.keysym=="Down":
        e.widget.tk_focusNext().focus()
    elif e.keysym=="Up":
        pass
[...]
root.bind_all("<Key>",select)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function you are looking for is `tk_focusPrev()`.